# FUnctions on Datekey

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want MonthName and MonthNumber from Datekey variable EX:20141217. I need output as

```
Month Name: December MonthNumber: 12
```

I tried to convert Datekey into DateTime variable using expression

```
convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),InvoiceCreateDateKey,120))
```

and top of it I used Month function to get MonthNumber.

```
MONTH(convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),InvoiceCreateDateKey,120)))
```

and this following expression for MonthName

```
DATENAME(m,convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),InvoiceCreateDateKey,120)))
```

I want to know are there any other functions in sql that I can use other than this complicated expressions? I want  to simplify those expressions. Using above expressions my sql query is taking very very long time to execute.

Comment: Are you certain the functions are the reason for poor query performance? I wouldn't expect some simple conversions to have any sort of drastic effect on query performance unless you have them in a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a date dimension table in you database? It would add a join but would eliminate function calls and clean up complicated expressions. You could store the format you want as a column in this table for each date and join on date key. They are also very useful for aggregating data by various time slices. I used this to start mine: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho but there are other ones out there as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUBSTRING to get the 5th and 6th characters of the Datekey string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 112 conversion for full date name

```
datename(month, convert(date, convert(nvarchar(10),InvoiceCreateDateKey), 112))
```

Also you can use datepart for getting month number

```
datepart(M,convert(date, convert(nvarchar(10),InvoiceCreateDateKey), 112))
```